# 2 questions on "test groups" using TestNG

Tags: testng

I am unable to find an answer to this specific basic question anywhere online. Please see below.

Example - I have 3 test methods in the same class -

```
@Test(groups = { "login", "sev1" })
public void ValidateUrlRedirectsCorrectly1() throws Exception {
}

@Test(groups = { "login" })
public void ValidateUrlRedirectsCorrectly2() throws Exception {
} 

@Test(groups = { "login" })
public void ValidateUrlRedirectsCorrectly3() throws Exception {
}
```

1. is there a way I can run just the group which is login + sev1?
2. if I include group as "login" in the above scenario - it will run all tests including ones with login + sev1. correct?

truly sorry. I've looked up testng documentation and several other help online and I couldn't find for this specific scenario. Any guidance would be great please. thank you

Comment: Not available in TestNG . In JUnit 5 you can do this for tags .:: & – to include where intersected 2 or more tagged tests from execution. Example: mvn test -Dgroups="api & performance" includes only if tagged “api” and “performance” both for the tests.

Comment: ok, thank you for the response